# Determine if a received email was forwarded, using ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing, email, email-client

Imagine that you receive and parse an email using [the ruby Mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail). I need to be able to determine if the email has been forwarded, and extract the original sender and message. By this I mean forwarded as in a user somewhere has clicked the "Forward" button in their email client or webmail interface.

I guess my questions are:

1. Are there are any concrete rules for what email clients should do to a forwarded message?
2. If so, where can I find them?
3. If not, would anyone like to volunteer to forward me some example emails from various different email clients so that I can build a reliable forwarded email detector and parser (the examples would be anonymized and the detector/parser will be open-sourced as a ruby gem on GitHub)?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes, they should attach the forwarded email or include it on the body
2. You need to parse yourself the emails and try to detect that.
3. I don't have this ... sorry!

Each email client can do whatever they want. So even if you create a detector/parsaer today, tomorrow with a new version of outlook/thunderbird probably it will not match.

Comment: That's cool, we can just keep adding examples and updating our code. There are other projects which have to do this: http://blog.mobileesp.com/